# Communication between uitableviewcells

Tags: swift, xcode

I have two UITableViewCells. I am trying to create a UI in the second uitableviewcell when the action of a button in the first tableview cell is triggered. I tried delegates but it didn't work.

```
protocol ProductColorTableViewCellDelegate {
    func changeUnit(selectedColor: String, _ modelArray : [UnitAndColors])
}

class ProductColorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { 
var delegate: ProductColorTableViewCellDelegate?

 @objc private func selectColor(_ sender : UIButton) {
    let tag : Int = sender.tag
    guard let model : UnitAndColors = self.arrayUnitsAndColor?[tag] else { return }
    delegate?.changeUnit(selectedColor: model.colorDesc ?? "", arrayUnitsAndColor ?? [])
}
}
```

Second tableviewcell

```
class PackagingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { 

let productColorTableViewCell = ProductColorTableViewCell()
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    productColorTableViewCell.delegate = self
    
}
}

extension PackagingTableViewCell: ProductColorTableViewCellDelegate {
    func changeUnit(selectedColor: String, _ modelArray: [UnitAndColors]) {
        selectedColorName = selectedColor
        self.unitStackView.removeAllArrangedSubviews()
        self.arrayUnitsAndColor?.removeAll()
        self.arrayUnitsAndColor = modelArray
        let filteredArray = self.arrayUnitsAndColor?.unique { $0.colorDesc == selectedColorName }
        var i : Int = 0
        filteredArray?.forEach { units in
            let vw = self.createUnits(units, tag: i)
            self.unitStackView.addArrangedSubview(vw)
            vw.snp.makeConstraints {
                $0.size.equalTo(40.0)
            }
            i = i + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use delegates. when you click on cell button trigger the delegate from the cell then make all required changes in the second tableview cell and reload the table view

Comment: I tried to use delegate but it didn't work, I couldn't understand what was wrong. Let me edit the question and show you what I did.

Comment: What about using `NotificationCenter`?

Comment: Is your tableView going to have only two rows? If yes, it sounds like you need to rethink the type of UIView you're using. UITableViews are for single-column vertically scrollable content.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Anwuna, thanks for information but I have more than two rows, I just shared what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ProductColorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { 
var delegate: ProductColorTableViewCellDelegate?
 @IBOutlet weak var selectColorButtonOL: UIButton!
 @IBAction func selectColor(_ sender : UIButton) {
    let tag : Int = sender.tag
    guard let model : UnitAndColors = self.arrayUnitsAndColor?[tag] else { return }
    delegate?.changeUnit(selectedColor: model.colorDesc ?? "", arrayUnitsAndColor ?? [])
}
}
```

```
extension ViewController: UItableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductColorTableViewCell") as! ProductColorTableViewCell
      cell.delegate = self
      cell.selectColorButtonOL.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
}
```

```
extension ViewController: ProductColorTableViewCellDelegate{
func changeUnit(selectedColor: String, _ modelArray: [UnitAndColors]) {
        // implement what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to change ui but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next cell by passing indexPath.row + 1 to tableView.cellForRowAt() and then call your function that does the required task.